# Fire success function in MVC using ajax for text file data

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

I'm simple fetching data from text file Which is on my desktop and display on alert dialog.This code perfectly worked for me if I use this as separate file on my desktop as html file with textfile.But when I include this code given below in MVC Project.It does not work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">   </script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("button").click(function(){
         $.ajax({
            url: "C://Users/Arslan/Desktop/mydata.txt",
            success:function(result){
           //$("#div1").html(result);
            alert(result);
          },
            error: function (er) {
             alert(er);
            }
       });
   }); 
});

 </script>
 </head>
  <body>
  <div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>

  <button>Get External Content</button>

 </body>
</html>
```

It is my MVC View code which contain link for this html page

```
<a href="<%=Url.Action("CallToHtmlPage", "FormData", new {filePath=@"~/Views/FormData/AjaxCode.html"})%>">Come here</a>
```

It's Controller code

```
 public class FormDataController : Controller
 {
    //
    // GET: /FormData/

    public ActionResult CallToHtmlPage(string filePath)
    {
        return new FilePathResult(filePath,"text/html");
    }
 }
```

And Finaly My text file(mydata.txt) contain only text value like my email address.That's it

Main Problem I'm facing is success function is not calling from ajax.It throw me error such type of [object Object].
Help me,Thanks

Comment: what are you trying to return from the ajax call? the filename? filepath? the text in the file?

Comment: the text in file Bro :)

Comment: Any one can help me like hard swimming in river

Comment: what is the actual error message you are getting from the ajax call? is it a exception from mvc? if so what was the content of exception? I was thinking maybe you file path does not exist?

Comment: [object Object] this type of errror and when I use er.responseText say undefined

Comment: But when I exclude this html file from my project.Then their is  no issue for Path of file But when I include this html  page in mvc and link it then error turn up.